# BackboneRelational issue with MarionetteCollectionView

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-relational

Currently, we are using nested attributes that are getting saved in the collection view being sent back to the server. For some reason, Marionette creates the new view in the collection just fine, but then it goes through the collection, closing,destroying,and rerendering all the views throughout the collection. Does anybody know what it could possibly be doing that? Just attributes that are not recognized that would have the whole collection updated many times? I also tried

```
.save(null,{merge:false})
```

which somewhat helped but still had some crazy issues creating views in the collection.

Edit: Basically, when I load things from the server everything is fine. After I save a model in the collection, things start to go crazy by firing different events that will add/remove from it.

Comment: can you provide your code to see how you are initialising the view

Comment: I have similar problem and tracked that CompositeView is bind to "add", while backbone.save save fires "add" events twice. It is probably because BackboneRelational creates temporary objects and one of the events is fired on them. Also when the server returns the new object the whole .set() routine is run again, which creates additional events.